# Unable to locate either of the radio buttons if both values are same

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am a newbie to learn Selenium please help me out on locating a radio button.

When I try to click a radio button(Static or dynamic) I couldn’t click either or those
[image]
I tried below commands using Xpath. But none of them worked

1.`//input[@type='radio' and @value='on'][1]`

2.`//p[text()='Static']`

Commands tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @value='on'][1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text()='Static'])[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Static']")).click();
```

The HTML script for the radio button as obtained from developer tools:

```
<div class="Radio__radio___1xD3w" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 36px; margin-top: 10px;"> ==$0
<input type="radio" class="Radio__radio-btn___E4u40" name="" value="on"><p class="Radio__radio-label___26Ok6">Static</p>
</div>
<div class="Radio__radio___1xD3w" style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 10px;">==$0
<input type="radio" class="Radio__radio-btn___E4u40" name="" value="on">
<p class="Radio__radio-label___26Ok6">Dynamic</p></div>
```

Code trials:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[text()='Static'])[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Static']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio' and @value='on'][1]")).click();
```

Comment: Did you get an exception? Share it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the *radio button* associated with the text  **Static** is a dynamic element to invoke `click()` on it you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[starts-with(@class,'Radio__radio-label___') and contains(., 'Static')]//preceding::input[1]"))).click();
  ```